# Let $A\le B$ and $B\le C$. What are the possibilities of ${\rm ord}(B)$ if ${\rm ord}(A)=60$ and ${\rm ord}(C)=4200?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I had a nice problem in my abstract algebra homework, and when I wanted to go deeper and generalize it, I got a little bit stuck.

> Let $A$ be a subgroup in $B$ and $B$ be a subgroup in $C$. Is there any equation that can connect ${\rm ord}(A)$, ${\rm ord}(B)$, ${\rm ord}(C)$?

I would appreciate if you can point me in the right direction.

Comment: **Hint:** Lagrange's Theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Lagrange's Theorem, ${\rm ord}(A)=60\mid {\rm ord}(B)$ and $ {\rm ord}(B)\mid 4200={\rm ord}(C)$.